# Solve the ODE $y'(t)=\frac{5t^4+1}{5y(t)^4+1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It has been a little time that I last solved ODEs. I think this one is a seperable one so we have $$y'(t)=\frac{5t^4+1}{5y(t)^4+1} \Leftrightarrow \int5y(t)^4+1dy=\int5t^4+1dt$$ Which gives $$y(t)^5+y(t)=t^5+t+c$$ I am not sure how to go on with this Equation, since the identity is obviously no solution. Furthermore I found that $\sqrt[5]{t^5+t}$ satisfies the ODE 
$y'(t)=\frac{5t^4+1}{5y(t)^4}$, so I am only missing a $+1$ in the denominator. Is there a trick to get the real solution from here? Thank you

EDIT: I forgot that $y(0)=0$

Comment: $y^5+y - 5t^5-t-c = 0$ is quintic equation in terms of $y$ and it generally does not have a closed form solution. So this "implicit" solution is as good as it gets.

Comment: Check coefficient of $t^5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y'(t)=\frac{5t^4+1}{5y(t)^4+1} $

$\int5y(t)^4+1dy=\int5t^4+1dt$

$y(t)^5 + y(t) = t^5 + t + c$

Since $y(0) = 0 \therefore c = 0$

$y(t)^5 + y(t) = t^5 + t$

$\therefore y(t) = t$

Comment: I see my mistake, somehow I did not see that I get the right thing if I plug in $y(t)=t$

Comment: I have no idea what you wrote but it looks beautiful, I hope I could understand more math